# ValueError: setup did not yield a value- When I try to run Azure Devops Pipeline / Pytest

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, pytest

For a while now I have been getting an error when I attemp to run an Azure Devops pipeline that I have created in order to execute a Pytest script. Actually if I run the script locally it is working properly, but when I run it though the pipeline I am facing the following error:

2023-04-21T12:03:42.0106817Z _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
2023-04-21T12:03:42.0107147Z
2023-04-21T12:03:42.0107597Z fixturefunc = <function setup at 0x00000215DC76A170>
2023-04-21T12:03:42.0108201Z request = <SubRequest 'setup' for >
2023-04-21T12:03:42.0108769Z kwargs = {'request': <SubRequest 'setup' for >}
2023-04-21T12:03:42.0109118Z
2023-04-21T12:03:42.0109541Z     def call_fixture_func(
2023-04-21T12:03:42.0110128Z         fixturefunc: "_FixtureFunc[FixtureValue]", request: FixtureRequest, kwargs
2023-04-21T12:03:42.0110603Z     ) -> FixtureValue:
2023-04-21T12:03:42.0111040Z         if is_generator(fixturefunc):
2023-04-21T12:03:42.0111478Z             fixturefunc = cast(
2023-04-21T12:03:42.0111946Z                 Callable[..., Generator[FixtureValue, None, None]], fixturefunc
2023-04-21T12:03:42.0112395Z             )
2023-04-21T12:03:42.0112831Z             generator = fixturefunc(**kwargs)
2023-04-21T12:03:42.0113267Z             try:
2023-04-21T12:03:42.0113703Z                 fixture_result = next(generator)
2023-04-21T12:03:42.0114150Z             except StopIteration:
2023-04-21T12:03:42.0114626Z >               raise ValueError(f"{request.fixturename} did not yield a value") from None
2023-04-21T12:03:42.0115124Z E               ValueError: setup did not yield a value

I cannot identify what is the problem, specifically I have the conftest file in this way:

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def setup(request):
global driver
browser_name = request.config.getoption("browser_name")
# Define variables for all Bankingly environments
demo_url= "https://....."
staging_url = "https://....."

```
if browser_name == "chrome":
    s = Service("..\\webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opt, service=s)
elif browser_name == 'edge':
    driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path="..\\webdrivers\\msedgedriver.exe")
client_name = request.config.getoption("client")
if client_name == "demo":
    driver.get(demo_url)
    driver.maximize_window()
    request.cls.driver = driver
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    yield
    driver.close()
    return driver
elif client_name == "staging":
    driver.get(staging_url)
    driver.maximize_window()
    request.cls.driver = driver
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    yield
    driver.close()
    return driver
```

Does anyone have any idea about the cause and the alternatives to fix this error?

Thank you in advance!

Mariano

I have tried to add a return clause after yield but it does no working as well